# winRT drag and drop, swap two items instead of inserting

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm a long time WPF user but new to WinRT. I'm wondering if there's a built in way or easy way to integrate swapping functionality in containers so that a swap exchanges two items in the container. The behavior desired is drag an item and drop it on another item and have both the dragged item and the item it's dragged onto get their positions in the container swapped).

Example I have a list with 1 2 3 *4* 5 6 *7* 8, if I drag *7* "on" *4* I want the two items swapped so that the resulting list becomes 1 2 3 *7* 5 6 *4* 8

I'm currently using a `GridView` with an `ItemsWrapGrid` as it's container to display a lot of picture thumbnails. I need to be able to reorder them with the most commonly required action being a swap in the positions of two images.

Or if there's no built in way, can you hint me at what the "proper" direction to start doing it from scratch would be in WinRT? I'm thinking handle the drag and drop not at the container but at the item level, and manually swap the items in the `ObservableCollection`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both existing answers will do the swapping for you, at the data level. Here's what can be done to make the UI more user-friendly.

IMHO, the best UX to handle the swapping is, when you drag an item and move it over another, the latter should *appear* to where the dragged item was originally at. This clearly tells the user where exactly the items will go. Just like what's shown on the gif image below.

[image: drag, drop & swap]

To do this you will need to create an `Image` and use `RenderTargetBitmap` to copy the look of the **drop item** to its source, when the **drag item** moves over the **drop item**. Of course when the drag action starts, you need to get the position of the **drag item** so you know where exactly to put this image.

Then, once the item is dropped, you should clear and hide the image and do the data exchange.

```
private void GridView_DragItemsStarting(object sender, DragItemsStartingEventArgs e)
{
    // get item container, i.e. GridViewItem
    var itemContainer = (GridViewItem)this.MyGridView.ContainerFromItem(e.Items[0]);

    // get drag item index from its item container
    _dragItemIndex = this.MyGridView.IndexFromContainer(itemContainer);

    // get drag item position
    var position = itemContainer.GetRelativePosition(this.LayoutRoot);

    // set the width and height of the image
    this.DropItemImage.Width = itemContainer.ActualWidth;
    this.DropItemImage.Height = itemContainer.ActualHeight;

    // move the image to this location
    this.DropItemImage.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0, 0);
    this.DropItemImage.RenderTransform.Animate(null, position.X, "TranslateX", 0, 0);
    this.DropItemImage.RenderTransform.Animate(null, position.Y, "TranslateY", 0, 0);
}

private void GridView_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    // first we need to reset the image
    this.DropItemImage.Source = null;

    // get the drop & drop items
    var dragItem = _groups[_dragItemIndex];
    var dropItem = _groups[_dropItemIndex];

    // then we swap their positions
    _groups.RemoveAt(_dragItemIndex);
    _groups.Insert(_dragItemIndex, dropItem);
    _groups.RemoveAt(_dropItemIndex);
    _groups.Insert(_dropItemIndex, dragItem);
}

private object _previous;
private async void ItemRoot_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    // first we get the DataContext from the drop item in order to retrieve its container
    var vm = ((Grid)sender).DataContext;

    // get the item container
    var itemContainer = (GridViewItem)this.MyGridView.ContainerFromItem(vm);

    // this is just to stop the following code to be called multiple times druing a DragOver
    if (_previous != null && _previous == itemContainer)
    {
        return;
    }
    _previous = itemContainer;

    // get drop item index from its item container
    _dropItemIndex = this.MyGridView.IndexFromContainer(itemContainer);

    // copy the look of the drop item to an image
    var bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
    await bitmap.RenderAsync(itemContainer);
    this.DropItemImage.Source = bitmap;

    // animate the image to make its appearing more interesting
    this.DropItemImage.Animate(0, 0.4, "Opacity", 200, 0);
    this.DropItemImage.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
    this.DropItemImage.RenderTransform.Animate(0.8, 1, "ScaleX", 200, 0, new ExponentialEase { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseIn });
    this.DropItemImage.RenderTransform.Animate(0.8, 1, "ScaleY", 200, 0, new ExponentialEase { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseIn });
}
```

I have included a small sample project [here](http://1drv.ms/1tRwf6W) just so you can check out how the animations are done. Please note that the data swapping part is not included, as I said, the other answers already explain it very well. :)

Comment: Thanks, this does show me a good way to change drag and drop visual behavior on top of just data. I think it would be nice if you also included the data swaping within your answer as it would make other people searching for an answer immediately find everything they need in the accepted answer.

Comment: @JustinXL In danger of resurrecting a dead thread: could you please provide a new link to your sample code? I’m struggling with the problem of keeping a `VisualBrush` alive during the drag operation, i.e., I’ve solved the data problem, but not the visual feedback one. Your answer looks as if you’ve mastered this perfectly.

Comment: @Informagic interesting. I can download it fine. If you can share me with your email address I will forward it to you.

Comment: @JustinXL Thank you, much obliged—I tried the link again, but it says that it’s dead and that I should contact the owner. I’ve added my e-mail address to my profile; please use that to forward the code sample. And again, thank you very much!

Comment: @JustinXL Just wanted to say thank you; I’ve upped your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to leverage `ObservableCollection`, and let the `ListBox` or w/e control take care of the rest.

All you have to do is, basically, create drag & drop handler, figure out which item client wanted to move where(keep track of oldIndex / newIndex), and implement the swap:

```
var dragSourceItem = yourObservable[oldIndex];
var dragTargetItem = yourObservable[newIndex];
yourObservable[newIndex]=dragSourceItem;
yourObservable[oldIndex]=dragTargetItem;
```

`ObservableCollection` will raise ´Replaced` action, WPF knows how to take care of.

Here's something to get you going: http://www.hardcodet.net/2009/03/moving-data-grid-rows-using-drag-and-drop

You'd basically want to wrap it into attached behavior, and implement the swap in `ViewModel`.

Comment: I'm not using WPF but winrt, i know about changing the data in the observable, the issue is how to properly implement the drag & drop swap itself (not how to update the underlying data). Should i do it at the item level, should i cancel the event so that it doesn't try to swap itself etc etc.

Comment: @RonanThibaudau: WPF or no WinRT, doesn't matter - one has just less functionality, and needs extra-hacking to compensate for lack of features (sometimes). The main philosophy is still the same. In WPF community, we use gongdrop (MVVM) - https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop I'd advise you to study how the problem has been solved, and adapt it to your use case. It supports re-ordering of elements.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it (with thanks to this [blog](http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2010/11/swapping-two-elements-in-bound.html)):

XAML code:

```
 <ListView x:Name="MyListView" CanDragItems="True" AllowDrop="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" DragItemsStarting="MyListView_DragItemsStarting" Drop="MyListView_Drop">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" AllowDrop="True" Drop="TextBlock_Drop" DragOver="TextBlock_DragOver"/>
            </DataTemplate>                
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

C# code:

```
ObservableCollection<string> MyList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
string DraggedString;
TextBlock DraggedOverTextBlock;

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        MyList.Add("1");
        MyList.Add("2");
        MyList.Add("3");
        MyList.Add("4");
        MyList.Add("5");
        MyList.Add("6");
        MyList.Add("7");
        MyList.Add("8");
        MyList.Add("9");
        MyList.Add("10");
        MyListView.ItemsSource = MyList;
    }

    private void MyListView_DragItemsStarting(object sender, DragItemsStartingEventArgs e)
    {
        DraggedString = e.Items[0] as String;
    }

    private void MyListView_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DraggedString == null || DraggedOverTextBlock == null) return;
        var indexes = new List<int> { MyList.IndexOf(DraggedString), MyList.IndexOf(DraggedOverTextBlock.Text) };
        if (indexes[0] == indexes[1]) return;
        indexes.Sort();
        var values = new List<string> { MyList[indexes[0]], MyList[indexes[1]] };
        MyList.RemoveAt(indexes[1]);
        MyList.RemoveAt(indexes[0]);
        MyList.Insert(indexes[0], values[1]);
        MyList.Insert(indexes[1], values[0]);
        DraggedString = null;
        DraggedOverTextBlock = null; 
    }

    private void TextBlock_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        DraggedOverTextBlock = sender as TextBlock;
    }
```

Comment: The blog post you're basing this on related to Silverlight, i'm looking for the best possible WinRT solution (not wpf or Silverlight), so i'm not going to accept this right now in case there is a better WinRT solution. This just uses regular drag and drop and swap items in the collection manually, i know how to manipulate a collection my question is strictly about the correct way to implement the WinRT part (am i better off sticking to drag and drop and abusing it, should i implement something else instead, if i use drag and drop is there a way to make it works well with transitions etc)

Comment: This blog post was Silverlight but the code is strictly WinRT. ObservableCollection is used in Silverlight, WPF and WinRT, so the code is the same for swapping item order.

There is no built-in reordering function, it's roll-your-own.

Source:  I'm a Microsoft Engineer.

Comment: Oki sounds good, so for you roll your own but do use the base drag & drop and override functionality right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that.  I think you're overthinking this.  The drag and drop functionality for FrameworkElement (the base for most controls) is accessed via the various events (DragItemsStarting, Drop, DragOver, etc.), so those are all you need to use, which is what I did.

Comment: No i understand how drag and drop works perfectly, i'm just not sure if drag and drop IS the proper way to implement swaping (i see how it can be a workaround, but i'm wondering if i should implement it WITH drag and drop or simply create my own mouse events to create a "drag and swap" that is it's own "thing" and not a derivative of drag and drop).

Comment: There's no simple or out-of-box way to do this. You will need to manually create the animation transition if you want something like - the drop item smoothly going towards the position where the drag item was originally from.

Comment: @JustinXL Could you post an answer with a rough outline of what would need to be done? I'm not necessarily looking for something simple or out of the box, just something that is the best way to do this cleanly / in WinRT fashion.