# Drag and Drop a control between grid cells within an Windows 10 Universal App

Tags: c#, xaml, drag-and-drop, grid, uwp

What I try to achieve is being able to drag an image from one cell and drop it into another cell in the same grid. This grid in xaml is defined as below:

```
 <Grid Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" AllowDrop="True" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Image Margin="10,10,10,10" CanDrag="True" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Source="Assets\mock.png" Width="64" Height="64" DropCompleted="Image_DropCompleted"/>
        <Image Margin="10,10,10,10" CanDrag="True" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Source="Assets\mock.png" Width="64" Height="64" DropCompleted="Image_DropCompleted"/>
        <Image Margin="10,10,10,10" CanDrag="True" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Source="Assets\mock.png" Width="64" Height="64" DropCompleted="Image_DropCompleted"/>
    </Grid>
```

When I drop an image from one cell to another, Image_DropCompleted is triggered, and I can use static function in Grid to set the row and column index.

So my questions is how to calculate these indexes from current mouse position?

Comment: You can of course try to calculate the position like that. But alternatively, you can use a GridView with built-in drag n drop support. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27741599/winrt-drag-and-drop-swap-two-items-instead-of-inserting

Comment: @JustinXL Thanks for your reply. I'm new to WinRT. It seems it's the perfect choice for grouping one image and a text as one item and allowing them to be dragged around as one. But is it possible that I can manually set the column and row index for each item? And could I specify the minimum row and column numbers? It looks like people use it with data binding in most of the cases.